# How do I use min/max on a nested field in rethinkdb

Tags: json, database, rethinkdb

I'm trying to determine the best way to calculate the elapsed time it took for each operation, series of actions. Looking at my example data below, how might I take the min/max for the "actions" array, for each corresponding operation, which includes 'take' and 'throw' actions:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "location" : "here",
  "operation" "hammer use",
  "actions" : [
    {
      "action" : "take",
      "object" : "hammer",
      "timestamp" : "12332234234"
    },
    {
      "action" : "drop",
      "object" : "hammer",
      "timestamp" : "12332234255"
    },
    {
      "action" : "take",
      "object" : "hammer",
      "timestamp" : "12332234266"
    },
    {
      "action" : "throw",
      "object" : "hammer",
      "timestamp" : "12332234277"
    }
},
{
  "name" : "test 2",
  "location" : "there",
  "operation" : "rock use",
  "actions" : [
    {
      "action" : "take",
      "object" : "rock",
      "timestamp" : "12332534277"
    },
    {
      "action" : "drop",
      "object" : "rock",
      "timestamp" : "12332534288"
    },
    {
      "action" : "take",
      "object" : "rock",
      "timestamp" : "12332534299"
    },
    {
      "action" : "throw",
      "object" : "rock",
      "timestamp" : "12332534400"
    },
{
  "name" : "test 3",
  "location" : "elsewhere",
  "operation" : "seal hose",
  "actions" : [
    {
      "action" : "create",
      "object" : "grommet",
      "timestamp" : "12332534277"
    },
    {
      "action" : "place",
      "object" : "grommet",
      "timestamp" : "12332534288"
    },
    {
      "action" : "tighten",
      "object" : "hose",
      "timestamp" : "12332534299"
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
"operation" : "hammer use",
"elapsed_time" : 123
},
{
"operation" : "rock use",
"elapsed_time" : 123
}
```

I'm still new to rethinkdb and trying to get a hang for it. So far, I've come up with the following query to pick the specific records, i'm interested in, from the table:

```
r.db('test').table('operations').filter(function(row) {
  return row('actions').contains(function(x) { 
    return x('action').eq('take')}).and(
      row('actions').contains(function(x) { return x('action').eq('throw') })
  );
});
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to aggregate the results by taking the min/max of the timestamp and subtracting them from each other.

I hope there's enough detail there to get an idea for the goal at hand. Let me know otherwise. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody tugged on this so I had to solve it without any help. Took a bit longer but finally figured out how. Here's the pseudocode for finding min/max on the nested fields above, and elapsed_time:

```
r.db('test').table('operations').filter(function(row) { 
  return row('actions').contains(function(x) { return x('action').eq("take") }).and(
    row('actions').contains(function(x) { return x('action').eq("throw") })
  ); 
}).map(function(doc) {
  return { 
    operation: doc('operation'),
    min: doc('actions')('timestamp').min(), 
    max: doc('actions')('timestamp').max(),
    elapsed_time: doc('actions')('timestamp').max().sub(doc('actions')('timestamp').min())
  }
})
```